# Redirect URL to PHP only if file does not exist with Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I am trying to get Nginx to rewrite URL space ./data/(.+).png to serveImage.php?guid=$1

```
server {
    server_name my.server;
    listen 80;
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    root /var/www/my.server;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
        rewrite ^/data/(.+).png serveImage.php?guid=$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? `serveImage.php` does exist in the document root.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487365/how-do-i-force-redirect-all-404s-or-every-page-whether-invalid-or-not-to-the

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Rewriting did not seem to work as planned (nothing that appeared to access.log or error.log gave even a hint that the rule was even caught). I made a more generic router that might fit better the other yet unknown needs as well.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @router;
    index index.html index.php;
    error_page 403 = @router;
    error_page 404 = @router;
}

location @router {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /router.php?$1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing such a simple solution to an issue I've been trying to solve a while. Here, take 10 rep.

Answer (score 6):

Well if it's always `/data` I would create a specific location for it, like this

```
location ~ /data/(.+).png {
    try_files $uri /serveImage.php?guid=$1;
}
```

Try this and tell me if it works.

Comment: Oddly nothing. This looks correct and smells correct, but did not solve the issue, which can be due to IP conflicts (two IPs on the machine, other has a IP restricted wildcard) or something else.

Comment: Too make this work you must write the ~ sign after the location. It is needed when using regex.

Comment: yea you're right, it's odd I've missed it, thanks for the correction