# How do I force redirect all 404's (or every page, whether invalid or not) to the homepage?

Tags: redirect, nginx, http-status-code-404

Currently every invalid page is 500 (Internal Server Error) because I probably messed up with my server block configuration.

I decided to shut down my website a while ago and created a simple one-page, thank-you homepage. However old links and external sites are still trying to access other parts of the site, which no longer exists.

How do I force redirect all non-homepage (any invalid URL) to the homepage?

I tried with the following block, but it didn't work:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $document_uri/index.html;
}
```

My current configuration is (I don't even serve PHP files right now, ie homepage is simple html):

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    access_log /srv/www/example.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/example.com/logs/error.log;
    root /srv/www/example.com/public_html;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $document_uri/index.html;
    }

    # Disable favicon.ico logging
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # Allow robots and disable logging
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # Enable permalink structures
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite . /index.php last;
    }

    # Handle php requests
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 900;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 900;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 900;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    # Disable static content logging and set cache time to max
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        expires max;
    }

    # Deny access to htaccess and htpasswd files
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    # Deny access to hidden files (beginning with a period)
    location ~ /\. {
        access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Setting the error page to the home page like this

```
error_page 404 /index.html;
```

has a small problem, the status code of the home page will be "404 not found", if you want to load the home page with a "200 ok" status code you should do it like this

```
error_page 404 =200 /index.html;
```

This will convert the "404 not found" error code to a "200 ok" code, and load the home page

The second method which @jvperrin mentioned is good too,

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

but you need to keep 1 thing in mind, since it's the `location /` any asset that doesn't match another location and is not found will also load the `index.html`, for example missing images, css, js files, but in your case I can see you already have another location that's matching the assets' extensions, so you shouldn't face this problem.

Comment: I can't think of a situation where you need to "override" the real http status code. If a page is not found, it should return a 404 status code.

Comment: I remember that we once did need to do that at work, but I can't recall why.

Comment: @AlanChavez If you're running a shop, all visitors to your site should be "convert-able". If someone gets an old or broken URL, and sees the 404 page, he's worth $0. If you redirect him to the home page, there is the potential he'll look around. Sending a 200 status code all the time also ensures that tracking and analytics systems get as much data as possible -- many systems will see the 404 status and assume the page leads nowhere.

Comment: @William your bring up a good point, although as far as I know the biggest search engines frown upon "soft 404s" (pages that return a non-404|410 status code for 404 pages) because otherwise the bots will crawl and index a page that doesn't exist. I've never had an issue an analytics not tracking pages that return 404 codes, but of course I have not tried all the solutions out there.

Comment: i get  this:  nginx: [emerg] invalid value "=200" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:34
after adding the error_page option

Comment: i think you missed the ; at the end of the line

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady About "but you need to keep 1 thing in mind..." Do you refer to `error_page 404 =200 /index.html;` or second method? 404 to 200 method affects to files, scripts, etc too, absolute or relative paths. This is a problem because I need to apply this rule only to directories (URL paths without files) and I'm guessing how to do it.

Comment: @ProtectedVoid I'm not sure I understand correctly, you could add location blocks and then add error page inside the location block, this way it will only be applied on locations that match that block.
If I misunderstood you the please try to clarify the question/concern.

Comment: @ILikeTacos actually it's a really common need. Single page web apps need to redirect routes back to the single page.

Answer (score 45):

To get a true redirect you could do this:

in server block define the error-page you want to redirect like this:

```
# define error page
error_page 404 = @myownredirect;
error_page 500 = @myownredirect;
```

Then you define that location:

```
# error page location redirect 302
location @myownredirect {
  return 302 /;
}
```

In this case errors 404 and 500 generates HTTP 302 (temporary redirect) to / (could of course be any URL)

If you use fast-cgi for php or other these blocks must have the following added to send the errors "upstrem" to server-block:

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
```

Comment: This works for me. You saved my day. vote up.

Comment: Thank you, didn't come up myself with this trick.

Answer (score 7):

This solution for nginx hosted site:

Edit your virtual hosting file

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/vishnuku.com
```

Add this snippet in the server block

```
# define error page
error_page 404 = @notfound;

# error page location redirect 301
location @notfound {
    return 301 /;
}
```

In your php block put the fastcgi_intercept_errors set to on

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    # intercept errors for 404 redirect
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Final code will look like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name vishnuku.com;

    root /var/www/nginx/vishnuku.com;
    index index.php index.html;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/vishnuku.com.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/vishnuku.com.error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args /;
    }

    # define error page
    error_page 404 = @notfound;

    # error page location redirect 301
    location @notfound {
        return 301 /;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location = /nginx.conf {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need `fastcgi_intercept_errors` for PHP-FPM routing here if you add `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` under the `\.php$` location block.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding the following line after your `index` definition:

```
error_page 404 /index.html;
```

If that doesn't work, try changing your `try_files` call to the following instead:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

Hopefully one of those works for you, I haven't tested either yet.

Comment: I think this would work except that I get 500 for any invalid page instead of 404. Can you see anything else wrong with my config?

Comment: When I go to, say, `www.example.com/asdasasd/` (which doesn't exist), I get an error like `rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "404"`.

Comment: Both `error_page` and `try_files` won't work together, so try them individually instead of both together, since I think it redirects twice when they are used together.

Comment: It was something to do with the `location ~ \.php$` block since if I comment out that whole block, it works fine with the `error_page` and `try_files` together. Unfortunately, I don't really know *why* the php block is breaking this config.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this:**

```
error_page 404 $scheme://$host/index.html;
```

Answer (score 2):

Must use

```
"fastcgi_intercept_errors on;"
```

along with the custom redirect location like 
`error_page 404 =200 /index.html` or

as above

```
location @myownredirect {
  return 302 /;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi first there are a lot of different ways to redirect all the 404 to the home page 
this helps you in SEO 
make such u use

```
 fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
```

than add this following to your config

```
        error_page 404 =301 http://yourdomain.com/;
    error_page 403 /error403.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /var/www/html;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Came here when I was looking to implement similar where I'm using Nginx as a reverse proxy to a self-hosted [MinIO bucket](https://min.io/), and none of the above answers have this. So, if you're using `proxy_pass` and are intercepting errors, you can also handle this logic to redirect to the `index.html` page.

Handling URLs such as:

- http://localhost/ - 200 OK
- http://localhost/index.html - 200 OK
- http://localhost/non-existant/ - 404 Not Found

```r
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  location / {
    rewrite ^/$ /static/index.html break;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_pass http://something-to-proxy/static/;
  }

  error_page 404 /index.html;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another-**correct** way to redirect from error page to the home page. The setup example applies to the **nginx** server configuration file:

```
...
http {
    ...
    server{
        ...
        #Catch 40x errors: 
        error_page 400 401 402 403 404 = @RedirectToHome;

        #Catch 50x errors: 
        error_page 500 501 502 503 504 = @RedirectToHome;

        #We are now redirecting to the homepage of the site
        location @RedirectToHome {
            return 301 http://www.example.com;
            #return 301 https://www.example.com;
            #return 301 /;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

You should avoid setting `return 301 /;` if port forwarding to the server was performed somewhere, because this **nginx** redirection will then be performed to the port on which the server is listening for incoming connections. Therefore, it is better to set the correct hostname(site name) in this configuration.