# Angular 2.0 router not working on reloading the browser

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using Angular 2.0.0-alpha.30 version. When redirect to a different route, then refresh the browser , its showing Cannot GET /route.

Can you help me with figuring why this error happened.

Comment: I guess it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that one is for angular 1.x versions . I am facing the issue in angular 2.0.

Comment: Angular 2.0 uses a completely new router so the linked post is of no use now since its the old router

Comment: As I said if it is the pushState issue it is not Angular specific and can't be fixed by Angular but needs to be fixed on the server instead.

Comment: some server configuration is needed, have a look at this post for some more details (added answer bellow). its not advised to switch to the hash location strategy http://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-router/

Answer (score 153, accepted):

> The error you are seeing is because you are requesting http://localhost/route which doesn't exist. According to [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31457808/2463695).

When using html5 routing you need to **map all routes in your app(currently 404) to index.html** in your server side. Here are some options for you:

1. using live-server: https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server

   ```
   $live-server --entry-file=index.html`
   ```
2. using nginx: http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html

   ```
   error_page 404 /index.html
   ```
3. Tomcat - configuration of web.xml. From [Kunin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1736537/a-kunin)'s comment

   ```
   <error-page>
         <error-code>404</error-code>
         <location>/index.html</location>
   </error-page>
   ```

Comment: Since one needs server side support for html5 routing this works perfectly well. Thanx

Comment: Can I use nginx as a proxy to `pub serve`? That way I don't need to `pub build` a lot during development. I tried but [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) doesn't work very well with [`error_page`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page).

Comment: @FranklinYu I haven't done it before. Do you get it resolved?

Comment: Not yet. I thought the argument `uri` of `error_page` can be something like `localhost:8000/index.html`, but it didn't work. The example on the documentation hint that I can "pass error processing into a named location", but it didn't seem to work for me either.

Comment: Using nginx. , error_page 404 /index.html in the location of the app worked for me.  Thank you.

Comment: Using nginx. This works but then still displays a 404 in my browser console. Any workaround?

Comment: @RichardK.Campion
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19489441/2463695.
You can click at `edited` to view the old answer version

Comment: @flash that's why I wrote: error_page 404 =200 /index.html.

Comment: How can I fix that, if I'm using `ng build` to generate my app?

Comment: Tomcat - configuration of web.xml

<error-page>
       <error-code>404</error-code>
       <location>/index.html</location>
 </error-page>

Comment: does anyone know how to do this with npm's http-server: https://github.com/indexzero/http-server/issues/427

Comment: How to do it in IIS server?   
And if we redirect all the 404 error pages to index.html how should we handle the real 404 error page issue?

Comment: @TempO'rary you can handle it in client-side routing or you can define a regex rule in your server routing engine for known routes. For IIS server, unfortunately, I haven't used it before.

Comment: My Angular app resides directly on IIS. How should I manage this issue in such a circumstance?

Comment: @AKunin this tomcat config doesn't work for tomcat 9 ? I tried same in tomcat 9 but its not working

Comment: @user1608841 I didn't test it with Tomcat 9. I am still on Tomcat 8.5 - setting is working

Comment: If I deploy my Angular application to AWS S3 or Azure Blob storage or CDN, what can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 69):

*Disclaimer: this fix works with Alpha44*

I had the same issue and solved it by implementing the **HashLocationStrategy** listed in the Angular.io API Preview.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/HashLocationStrategy-class.html

Start by importing the necessary directives

```
import {provide} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  LocationStrategy,
  HashLocationStrategy
} from 'angular2/router';
```

And finally, bootstrap it all together like so

```
bootstrap(AppCmp, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

Your route will appear as http://localhost/#/route and when you refresh, it will reload at it's proper place.

Comment: this code will work fine but there is someProblem in this technique by using this `#` will added automaticaly in the URL. is there any solution to remove # from the URL by using this ?

Comment: Agreed, I tried implementing the "PathLocationStrategy" listed [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/PathLocationStrategy-class.html), but couldn't get it to work. A URL without the `#` would be optimal.

Comment: Yes me too tried the same with the `PathLocationStrategy` but this is not working for me. either i used wrong method or either i dont know how to use PathLocationStrategy.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in RC1. Importing LocationStrategy,  HashLocationStrategy from '@angular/router' fails.

Comment: @psych As indicated in the disclaimer, the solution I provided works for Alpha 44. This issue has since been fixed as of (RC.3). See Günter Zöchbauer's answer, apart of this thread.

Comment: We use https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed and the current version (based on angular2 rc.5) incorporates this.  However it was not in the version based on rc.4.

Comment: Sorry for coming back to this questions after more than 1 year :) But does HashLocationStrategy help stay on the same Router path? In my case when I refresh it takes me to http://localhost/#/<default route> i.e the default route for the home page. How do I go to the current route that I was originally on when I 'Refreshed'?

Answer (score 50):

Angular by default uses HTML5 pushstate (`PathLocationStrategy` in Angular slang).
You either need a server that processes all requests like it were requesting `index.html` or you switch to `HashLocationStrategy` (with # in the URL for routes) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/HashLocationStrategy-class.html

See also https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/

To switch to `HashLocationStrategy` use

**update for >= RC.5 and 2.0.0 final**

```ts
import {HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppCmp], 
  bootstrap: [AppCmp],
  imports: [BrowserModule, routes],
  providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]
]);
```

or shorter with `useHash`

```ts
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTER_CONFIG, {useHash: true}), ...
```

ensure you have all required imports

For the new (RC.3) router

```ts
<base href=".">
```

can cause 404 as well.

It requires instead

```ts
<base href="/">
```

---

**update for >= RC.x**

```ts
bootstrap(AppCmp, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
  // or since RC.2
  {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy} 
]);

import {provide} from '@angular/core';
import {  
  PlatformLocation,  
  Location,  
  LocationStrategy,  
  HashLocationStrategy,  
  PathLocationStrategy,  
  APP_BASE_HREF}  
from '@angular/common';
```

**update for >= beta.16** Imports have changed

```ts
import {BrowserPlatformLocation} from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {
  // PlatformLocation,
  // Location,
  LocationStrategy,
  HashLocationStrategy,
  // PathLocationStrategy,
  APP_BASE_HREF}
from 'angular2/router';
import {BrowserPlatformLocation} from 'angular2/src/router/location/browser_platform_location';
```

**< beta.16**

```ts
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {
  HashLocationStrategy
  LocationStrategy,
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
} from 'angular2/router';
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta16-2016-04-26 breaking-changes

Comment: Thanks! provide seems to have moved under angular/core: import {provide} from 'angular2/core'

Comment: Just to note: `update for >= RC.x` (RC.2) works with `router 3.0.0-alpha.7`, but `provide` annotated as deprecated without information about which function replaced it.

Comment: Use `{provide: SomeClass, useClass: OtherClass}`

Comment: Most updated answer. For the latest version of angular 2.4.1 I had <base href="./"> . Changed into <base href="/"> solved the issue I had. Might be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 30):

I think the error you are seeing is because your are requesting http://localhost/route which doesn't exist.  You need to make sure that your server will map all requests to your main index.html page.

As Angular 2 uses html5 routing by default rather than using hashes at the end of the url, refreshing the page looks like a request for a different resource.

Comment: so how do we fix that? how do we map all requests to main index by default? is it server-reliant?

Comment: Yes, you would do this on the server with whatever web framework you are using.  The alternative is to use the HashLocationStrategy as described below.

Comment: You will be reloading the angular SPA in every non present route. Is it how it should be handled?

Comment: It only reloads if the user clicks refresh on the browser, not when user changes routes through the UI. Not really any way around a reload when the user refreshes.

Answer (score 23):

This is a common situation in all router versions if you are using the default HTML location strategy.

What happens is that the URL on the browser bar is a normal full HTML url, like for example: `http://localhost/route`.

So when we hit Enter in the browser bar, there is an actual HTTP request sent to the server to get a file named `route`.

The server does not have such file, and neither something like express is configured on the server to handle the request and provide a response, so the server return 404 Not Found, because it could not find the `route` file.

What we would like is for the server to return the `index.html` file containing the single page application. Then the router should kick in and process the `/route` url and display the component mapped to it.

So to fix the issue we need to configure the server to return `index.html` (assuming that is the name of your single page application file) in case the request could not be handled, as opposed to a 404 Not Found.

The way to do this will depend on the server side technology being used. If its Java for example you might have to write a servlet, in Rails it will be different, etc.

To give a concrete example, if for example you are using NodeJs, you would have to write a middleware like this:

```
function sendSpaFileIfUnmatched(req,res) {
    res.sendFile("index.html", { root: '.' });
}
```

And then register it at the very end of the middleware chain:

```
app.use(sendSpaFileIfUnmatched);
```

This will serve `index.html` instead of returning a 404, the router will kick in and everything will work as expected.

Comment: This was exactly my issue. If you use NGINX, this answer helps resolve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027636/nginx-send-all-requests-to-a-single-html-page

Comment: Is there a tutorial on how to do this for java? Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Make sure this is placed in the head element of your index.html:

```
<base href="/">
```

The [Example](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html) in the Angular2 [Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles) documentation uses the following code in the head instead (they explain why in the live example note of the documentation):

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

When you refresh a page this will dynamically set the base href to your current document.location.  I could see this causing some confusion for people skimming the documentation and trying to replicate the plunker.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.  Let's just be clear, it only worked for me when I put <base href="/"> directly after loading all css in the <head>, and before loading ANY Js files . I hope it helps anyone

Comment: i have <base href="./"> in index.html then removed '.' from the href and it worked..

Answer (score 12):

If you want to be able to enter urls in browser without configuring your AppServer to handle all requests to index.html, you must use **HashLocationStrategy**.

The easiest way to configure is using:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
```

Instead of:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```

With **HashLocationStrategy** your urls gonna be like:

```
http://server:port/#/path
```

Comment: Thanks! this helps, But I dont want ```#``` from url, can we remove this?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with using webpack-dev-server. I had to add the devServer option to my webpack.

## Solution:

```
// in webpack
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal'
}
```

Comment: Kind of voodoo magic :p For more info, see : https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#the-historyapifallback-option

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Apache or Nginx as a server you have to create a `.htaccess` (if not created before) and "On" RewriteEngine

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Comment: Didn't get your question,this method tested on Apache and Nginx ( https://www.nginx.com/ )server

Comment: This is only for Apache; Nginx configuration format is totally different.

Answer (score 5):

My server is Apache, what I did to fix 404 when refreshing or deep linking is very simple. Just add one line in apache vhost config:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
```

So that any 404 error will be redirected to index.html, which is what angular2 routing wants.

The whole vhost file example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName fenz.niwa.local
  DirectoryIndex index.html
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.html

  DocumentRoot "/Users/zhoum/Documents/workspace/fire/fire_service/dist"
  ErrorLog /Users/zhoum/Documents/workspace/fire/fire_service/logs/fenz.error.log
  CustomLog /Users/zhoum/Documents/workspace/fire/fire_service/logs/fenz.access.log combined

  <Directory "/Users/zhoum/Documents/workspace/fire/fire_service/dist">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    #Order allow,deny
    #Allow from All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Accept-Encoding"
</VirtualHost>
```

**No matter what server you are using, I think the whole point is finding out the ways to config the server to redirect 404 to your index.html.**

Answer (score 4):

Server configuration is not a solution for an SPA is what even I think. You dont want to reload an angular SPA again if a wrong route comes in, do you? So I will not depend on a server route and redirect to other route but yes I will let index.html handle all the requests for angular routes of the angular app path.

Try this instead of otherwise or wrong routes. It works for me, not sure but seems like work in progress. Stumbled this myself when facing an issue.

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/**', redirectTo: ['MycmpnameCmp'] }, 
   ...
  }
])
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4055

However remember to configure your server folders and access right in case you have HTML or web scripts which are not SPA. Else you will face issues. For me when facing issue like you it was a mix of server configuration and above.

Answer (score 4):

for angular 5 quick fix, edit **app.module.ts** and add `{useHash:true}` after the appRoutes.

```
@NgModule(
{
  imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,{useHash:true})]
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this solution for mean application, I used ejs as view engine:

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    return res.render('index.html');
});
```

and also set in angular-cli.json

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "views",
```

it will work fine instead of

```
app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('dist/index.html', { root: __dirname });
 });
```

its creating issue with get db calls and returning index.html

Comment: This worked perfectly in October 2017 for MEAN stack application.

Answer (score 3):

Angular apps are perfect candidates for serving with a simple static HTML server. You don't need a server-side engine to dynamically compose application pages because Angular does that on the client-side.

If the app uses the Angular router, you must configure the server to return the application's host page (index.html) when asked for a file that it does not have.

A routed application should support "deep links". A deep link is a URL that specifies a path to a component inside the app. For example, http://www.example.com/heroes/42 is a deep link to the hero detail page that displays the hero with id: 42.

There is no issue when the user navigates to that URL from within a running client. The Angular router interprets the URL and routes to that page and hero.

But clicking a link in an email, entering it in the browser address bar, or merely refreshing the browser while on the hero detail page — all of these actions are handled by the browser itself, outside the running application. The browser makes a direct request to the server for that URL, bypassing the router.

A static server routinely returns index.html when it receives a request for http://www.example.com/. But it rejects http://www.example.com/heroes/42 and returns a 404 - Not Found error unless it is configured to return index.html instead

**If this issue occurred in production, follow below steps**

1) Add a Web.Config file in the src folder of your angular application. Place below code in it.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

2) Add a reference to it in angular-cli.json. In angular-cli.json put Web.config in assets block as shown below.

```
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "Web.config"
  ],
```

3) Now you can build the solution for production using

```
ng build --prod
```

This will create a dist folder. The files inside dist folder are ready for deployment by any mode.

Comment: Best solution, can find the details from angular: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback
While creating web.config file do not forget to add <configuration></configuration> tag. 
Thanks for the answer Malatesh.

Comment: Not working, I used 1. HashLocationStrategy 2. htaacess 3. web.config. Please suggest any  other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

For those of us struggling through life in IIS: use the following PowerShell code to fix this issue based on the official Angular 2 docs (that someone posted in this thread? http://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-router/)

```
Import-WebAdministration
# Grab the 404 handler and update it to redirect to index.html.
$redirect = Get-WebConfiguration -filter "/system.WebServer/httperrors/error[@statusCode='404']" -PSPath IIS:\Sites\LIS 
$redirect.path = "/index.html"
$redirect.responseMode = 1
# shove the updated config back into IIS
Set-WebConfiguration -filter "/system.WebServer/httperrors/error[@statusCode='404']" -PSPath IIS:\Sites\LIS -value $redirect
```

This redirects the 404 to the /index.html file as per the suggestion in the Angular 2 docs (link above).

Answer (score 2):

You can try out below. It works for me!

main.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

...
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private router: Router) {
        let path: string = window.location.hash;
        if (path && path.length > 0) {
            this.router.navigate([path.substr(2)]);
        }
    }

    public ngOnInit() { }
}
```

You can further enhance path.substr(2) to split into router parameters. I'm using angular 2.4.9

Comment: This was really helpful for handling browser refreshes! For angular 5, I had to modify it a bit to use window.location.pathname, and compare that value to expected paths.

Answer (score 2):

i Just adding .htaccess in root.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ ./index.html
</IfModule>
```

here i just add dot '.'(parent directory) in /index.html to  ./index.html
make sure your index.html file in base path is main directory path and set in build of project.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to preserve the URL path of sub pages in HTML5 mode without a redirect back to index and none of the solutions out there told me how to do this, so this is how I accomplished it:

Create simple virtual directories in IIS for all your routes and point them to the app root.

Wrap your system.webServer in your Web.config.xml with this location tag, otherwise you will get duplicate errors from it loading Web.config a second time with the virtual directory:

```
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
                <add value="index.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked in angular 2 seed how it works.

You can use [express-history-api-fallback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-history-api-fallback) to redirect automatically when a page is reload.

I think it's the most elegant way to resolve this problem IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use PathLocationStrategy :

- Wildfly configuration :

  - Create undertow-handlers.conf file to be placed in the WEB-INF
  - Content : (exclude your rest endpoints !)

    - regex['(.*/overview/?.*?$)'] and not regex['(.*/endpoints.*)'] ->    rewrite['/index.html']
    - regex['(.*/deployments/?.*?$)'] and not regex['(.*/endpoints.*)'] -> rewrite['/index.html']

[Single page application with Java EE/Wildfly: server-side configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127746/single-page-application-with-java-ee-wildfly-server-side-configuration)

Answer (score 1):

2017-July-11: Since this is [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945864/electron-app-with-angular-2-reload-issue) from a question having this problem but using Angular 2 with Electron, I'll add my solution here.

All I had to do was remove `<base href="./">` from my index.html and Electron started reloading the page again successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Add imports:

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

And in NgModule provider, add:

```
providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]
```

In main index.html File of the App change the base href to `./index.html` from `/`

The App when deployed in any server will give a real url for the page which can be accessed from any external application.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding **.htaccess** in root resolved 404 while refreshing the page in angular 4 apache2.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html
    # to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting 404 because your are requesting http://localhost/route which doesn't exist on tomcat server. As Angular 2 uses html 5 routing by default rather than using hashes at the end of the URL, refreshing the page looks like a request for a different resource.

When using angular routing on tomcat you need to make sure that your server will map all routes in your app to your main index.html while refreshing the page. There are multiple way to resolve this issue. Whichever one suits you you can go for that.

**1) Put below code in web.xml of your deployment folder :**

```
<error-page>
     <error-code>404</error-code>
     <location>/index.html</location>
</error-page>
```

**2) You can also try using HashLocationStrategy with # in the URL for routes :**

Try using:

RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })

Instead of:

RouterModule.forRoot(routes)

With HashLocationStrategy your urls gonna be like:

http://localhost/#/route

**3) Tomcat URL Rewrite Valve : Re-write the url's using a server level configuration to redirect to index.html if the resource is not found.**

3.1) Inside META-INF folder create a file context.xml and copy the below context inside it.

```
<? xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
</Context>
```

3.2) Inside WEB-INF, create file rewrite.config(this file contain the rule for URL Rewriting and used by tomcat for URL rewriting). Inside rewrite.config, copy the below content:

```
  RewriteCond %{SERVLET_PATH} !-f
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right answer but On-refresh you can redirect all dead calls to Homepage by sacrificing 404 page it's a temporary hack just replay following on 404.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "http://" + document.location.host;
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution of resolve the "router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser" is that we should use spa-fall back. If you are using angular2 application with asp.net core then we need to defined it on "StartUp.cs" page. under MVC routs. I am attaching the code.

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute("spa-fallback", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite tricky. If you use a plain old Apache Server (or IIS), you get the problem because the Angular pages do not exist for real. They are "computed" from the Angular route.

There are several ways to fix the issue. One is to use the [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy) offered by Angular. But a sharp sign is added in the URL. This is mainly for compatibility with Angular 1 (I assume). The fact is the part after the sharp is not part of the URL (then the server resolves the part before the "#" sign). That can be perfect.

Here an enhanced method (based on the 404 trick). I assume you have a "distributed" version of your angular application (`ng build --prod` if you use Angular-CLI) and you access the pages directly with your server and PHP is enabled.

If your website is based on pages (Wordpress for example) and you have only one folder dedicated to Angular (named "dist" in my example), you can do something weird but, at the end, simple. I assume you have stored your Angular pages in "/dist" (with the according `<BASE HREF="/dist/">`). Now use a 404 redirection and the help of PHP.

In your Apache configuration (or in the `.htaccess` file of your angular application directory), you must add `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`

The 404.php will start with the following code:

```
<?php
$angular='/dist/';
if( substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, strlen($angular)) == $angular ){
    $index = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $angular . "index.html";
    http_response_code(200);
    include $index;
    die;
}

// NOT ANGULAR...
echo "<h1>Not found.</h1>"
```

where `$angular` is the value stored in the HREF of your angular `index.html`.

The principle is quite simple, if Apache does not find the page, a 404 redirection is made to the PHP script. We just check if the page is inside the angular application directory. If it is the case, we just load the index.html directly (without redirecting): this is necessary to keep the URL unchanged. We also change the HTTP code from 404 to 200 (just better for crawlers).

What if the page does not exist in the angular application? Well, we use the "catch all" of the angular router (see Angular router documentation).

This method works with an embedded Angular application inside a basic website (I think it will be the case in future).

NOTES:

- Trying to do the same with the `mod_redirect` (by rewriting the URLs) is not at all a good solution because files (like assets) have to be really loaded then it is much more risky than just using the "not found" solution.
- Just redirecting using `ErrorDocument 404 /dist/index.html` works but Apache is still responding with a 404 error code (which is bad for crawlers).

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a permanent Fix for the problem but more like a workaround or hack**

I had this very same issue when deploying my Angular App to gh-pages.
First i was greeted with 404 messages when Refreshing my pages on gh-pages.

Then as what @gunter pointed out i started using `HashLocationStrategy` which was provided with Angular 2 .

But that came with it's own set of problems the `#` in the url it was really bad made the url look wierd like this `https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/faq`.

I started researching out about this problem and came across a blog. I tried giving it a shot and it worked .

Here is what i did as mentioned in that blog.

> You’ll need to start by adding a 404.html file to your gh-pages repo
>   that contains an empty HTML document inside it – but your document
>   must total more than 512 bytes (explained below). Next put the
>   following markup in your 404.html page’s head element:

```
<script>
  sessionStorage.redirect = location.href;
</script>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='/REPO_NAME_HERE'"></meta>
```

> This code sets the attempted entrance URL to a variable on the
>   standard sessionStorage object and immediately redirects to your
>   project’s index.html page using a meta refresh tag. If you’re doing a
>   Github Organization site, don’t put a repo name in the content
>   attribute replacer text, just do this: content="0;URL='/'"
>
> In order to capture and restore the URL the user initially navigated
>   to, you’ll need to add the following script tag to the head of your
>   index.html page before any other JavaScript acts on the page’s current
>   state:

```
<script>
  (function(){
    var redirect = sessionStorage.redirect;
    delete sessionStorage.redirect;
    if (redirect && redirect != location.href) {
      history.replaceState(null, null, redirect);
    }
  })();
</script>
```

> This bit of JavaScript retrieves the URL we cached in sessionStorage
>   over on the 404.html page and replaces the current history entry with
>   it.

Reference [backalleycoder](http://www.backalleycoder.com/2016/05/13/sghpa-the-single-page-app-hack-for-github-pages/) Thanks to @Daniel for this workaround.

Now the above URL changes to https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this (using Java / Spring backend) by adding a handler that matches everything defined in my Angular routes, that sends back index.html instead of a 404. This then effectively (re)bootstraps the application and loads the correct page. I also have a 404 handler for anything that isn't caught by this.

```
@Controller         ////don't use RestController or it will just send back the string "index.html"
public class Redirect {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Redirect.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = {"comma", "sep", "list", "of", "routes"})
    public String redirectToIndex(HttpServletRequest request) {
        logger.warn("Redirect api called for URL {}. Sending index.html back instead. This will happen on a page refresh or reload when the page is on an Angular route", request.getRequestURL());
        return "/index.html";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache or Nginx as a server you need to create a .htaccess

```
<IfModule mime_module>
      AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
    </IfModule>
    # php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html
        # to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use location strategy, Add `useHash: true` in routing file.

`imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })]`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am running an Angular app on an Azure hosted Linux box, the previously mentioned hash location strategy worked, but having the `#` in the URL wasn't what was wanted. Adding `--spa` to the configuration startup command allowed manually typing URLs. So my command is now this

`pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/ --no-daemon --spa`

More information on [Azure deployment with PM2](https://azureossd.github.io/2022/01/29/Angular-Deployment-on-App-Service-Linux/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using Angular project template with ASP.NET Core 7. After deploying to IIS (Web App on Azure), page refreshes started returning 404 error.

In `Program.cs` this is already handled with this line of code.

```
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
```

But if your `index.html` is inside a subfolder within `wwwroot`, this is how to configure it. (This was our case, therefore above line of code didn't really do anything.)

```
var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
    Path.Combine(app.Environment.WebRootPath, "MySubFolder"));
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html", new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = fileProvider,
    RequestPath = ""
});
```

This fixed our issue ([full Program.cs file](https://gist.github.com/nishanc/6dc687fc063eec176d9e1c50abff7108#file-program-cs)). If the `index.html` is in a folder (e.g.: ClientApp/dist) outside `wwwroot`, `fileProvider` should be created like this.

```
var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
    Path.Combine(app.Environment.ContentRootPath, "ClientApp", "dist", "index.html"));
```

Do not need a `web.config` file. Here's [our .csproj](https://gist.github.com/nishanc/16f6ba22146dcde8311ea56a6f9cafda#file-portal-app-csproj) file which also does not have significant change which would affect this issue.

Answer (score -3):

Simon's answer was correct for me.  I added this code:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendfile("dist/index.html");
});
```

Comment: express file ? if you have pls provide plnkr for your code it will helps to understand better.

Comment: this is not related with angular

Comment: @BranislavDjuric It's not, but it does solve the problem for anyone using node.js and express.

Comment: What happens when an image request comes in for an image that does not exist on disk? they get the index.html back?