# Angular 2 Page Routing Error

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

**Question**

Why cant I refresh on my routed page without getting errors?

**Problem**

I got an `onSelect` in my `<navigation>` directive and try to load my `PageComponent` into the `<router-outlet>`. This actually works, you can see that my page is loaded when you click the *test* navigation link.

In my real code, if I click on it, the url changes to `http://localhost:3000/page/10` (10 is just some id, not relevant). If I refresh now on the page I get the errors.

it seems like it searches the .js files on the wrong path `/page/node_modules` instead of `/node_modules/`

**Errors**

> GET http://localhost:3000/page/style.css 
>   GET http://localhost:3000/page/vendor.js 
>   GET http://localhost:3000/page/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js
>   GET http://localhost:3000/page/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js
>   GET http://localhost:3000/page/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js
>   GET http://localhost:3000/page/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js 
>   
>  
>   GET http://localhost:3000/page/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js
>   GET http://localhost:3000/page/node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js 
>   GET http://localhost:3000/page/node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js 
>   GET http://localhost:3000/page/node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined

**Setup**

I tried to set my example up on plunkr. But I guess you cant really refresh there to test my error exactly.

https://embed.plnkr.co/7P21IbHr8EOuUW7NjmFS/

Comment: Is your server configured to support HTML5 pushState? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer ty, good link. I kinda searched in the wrong direction. I could fix it temporary with using hashtags, which is probably not the best way. I guess I will try it server side as soon as im leaving my localhost setup :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could fix it with this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33573548/753628

The errors are there because the route actually doesnt exist. Therefore we need to use a # in the url.

```
import {provide} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  LocationStrategy,
  HashLocationStrategy
} from 'angular2/router';
```

And the bootstrap:

```
bootstrap(AppCmp, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

This changes my url to http://localhost:3000/#/page/10 which actually doesnt fail if refreshed.