# Routing not working in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular, angularjs-routing

My Routing isn't working in Angular2, to demonstrate the point, I have put the same component as the destination for both the root of my site and `/login`. The component works at `http://localhost:3000`, but at `http://localhost:3000/login`, I just get a notice "Cannot GET /login".

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/router';

import {TodoService} from './todo/services/todo.service';
import { TodoCmp } from './todo/components/todo.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './user/components/login.component';
import { UserService } from './user/services/user.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['client/dev/todo/styles/todo.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    TodoService
  ]
})
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'TodoCmp',
    component: TodoCmp,
    useAsDefault: true
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'TodoCmp',
    component: TodoCmp
  }
])

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ng2do';
}
```

Here is a link to my [index](https://github.com/georgeedwards/Gen-App/blob/master/client/dev/index.html) file.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: have you included all necessary library files?

Comment: @sdfacre Yes, I was facing an issue with my system.config not adding file extensions to dependencies. That is now resolved, please see my updated question.

Comment: if everything is loaded correctly, why it still complains 'require is not defined'...sorry, I don't have any clue unless you can provide a plunker. Have you followed any example? like http://www.waynehong.com/javascript/angular-2-routing-example-typescript/

Comment: please include your index.html

Comment: @Rick [Here](https://github.com/georgeedwards/Gen-App/blob/master/client/dev/index.html) is a link, I'll add it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two routes in one `@RouteConfig(...)` can't have the same name:

```
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'TodoCmp',
    component: TodoCmp,
    useAsDefault: true
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'TodoCmp',  <!-- <<<== should be 'Login' instead of 'TodoCmp'
    component: TodoCmp
  }
])
```

You should move `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` to `bootstrap()` (like `HTTP_PROVIDERS`)

Comment: I have added `import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';` and then changed my line to `bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);` in main.ts, but I still get the same behaviour, is that what you meant to do?

Comment: Did you also remove it from `@Component()`?

Comment: Yes, I removed it from `app.component`

Comment: Your routes have both the same `name: 'TodoCmp'`. The names need to be unique for routes of one component.

Comment: Did this fix your issue?

Comment: I am afraid not, I still get the `Failed to load resource: http://localhost:3000/login  the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: That's probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser

Comment: Either to enable `HashLocationStrategy` like explained by one of the answers to the linked question, or to use a server that properly handles HTML5 pushState