# Angular 2 not rendering dependancy links with file extensions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am getting the following errors while running my app:

[image]

It seems to be looking for `./app.component`, rather than `./app.component.js`

Here is my `main.ts` file:

```
import { bootstrap }    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

What have I done wrong to configure the dependencies here? NB: If I change the references to `import { AppComponent } from './app.component.js';`, then the error goes away and I am faced with more of the same errors for other references.

## EDIT:

One of the comments has suggested that there might be an issue with my system.config(), which I think sounds very plausible, however, this is and excerpt from my `index.html` file, which I can't see any issues with?

```
...    
<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('client/dev/main.js')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
...
```

Comment: The problem is in your System.config(), probably missing a `defaultExtension` or similar. Post your config and see the [quickstart guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) (look for *SystemJS configuration*)

Comment: @EricMartinez, I have set up my System.Config, but I still get these issues. Please see my index.html file I have added to the question, is that ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is probably that you have :

```
<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('client/dev/main.js')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

instead of

```
<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {       
      "client/dev": { // this line changed, here the directory where your generated `js` files are, has to be specified 
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('client/dev/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

I had exactly the same problem as you when I started ;)

Also the `zone` error should disappear if you use the newest angular beta build (12).

Comment: This has thrown up a new issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186425/routing-not-working-in-angular2), if you get a chance, I would be really grateful for your input.