# accordion (ng2-accordion) in angular2

Tags: typescript, npm, angular, accordion, ng2-bootstrap

Am using accordion with angular-2,but its not working properly,its throwing an  error 404, its a third-party plugin named "ng2-accordion".

Path of the package that am giving is correct.

Actual bug in the inspect is given below.

1. GET
   http://localhost:3000/ng2-accordion/ng2-accordion 404 (Not Found)
2. Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found)
   loading http://localhost:3000/ng2-accordion/ng2-accordion(…)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add mapping to your system.js configuration like this:

```
{
    "map": {
        "ng2-accordion": "node_modules/ng2-accordion"
    },
    "packages": {
        "ng2-accordion": { "main": "index.js", "defaultExtension": "js" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the directory structure for the `ng2-accordion` module. For example, for me the module is directory under `node_modules`.

So, specifying

```
import {ACCORDION_DIRECTIVES} from "ng2-accordion";
```

Instead of

```
import {ACCORDION_DIRECTIVES} from "ng2-accordion/ng2-accordion";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure your server to allow HTML5 pushState.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/36310728/217408

Comment: Sorry, I want to know, how to include an accordion in my project but it is not working,when the project was running,it showing error like above.

Comment: I know.  . . . . I updated the link to an answer with more information. Try switching to `HashLocationStrategy` if this solves the problem and you want to use `PathLocationStrategy` then you need to configure your server instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Path correct http://localhost:3000/ng2-accordion/ng2-accordion ?
 If so you might have missed adding the defaultextension and also check the LocationStatergy, i would prefer HashLocation.