# Angular 2 http request is giving pending/cancelled status on new system

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, http, express, angular

I'm sending http request as following

```
this.http.post('/api/login', body)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
                   ...
                  },
               error=> {
                   ...
                  });
```

But in new systems it gives pending then after that it gots cancelled sometimes.

After loading one time this never happens on that system again and works fine.
Basically I'm redirecting all client routes to index.html. As follows:

```
app.get(['/', '/login', '/dashboard'],function(req, res, next){
                    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/../public/index.html'));
                });
```

Where `'/', '/login', '/dashboard'` are routes at my client end. As follows:

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', redirectTo: ['/Dashboard'] },
  { path: '/login', component: Login, as: 'Login' },
  { path: '/dashboard', component: Dashboard, as: 'Dashboard' }
])
```

Comment: Why don't you configure the server to do the redirection?

Comment: To use `PathLocationStrategy` with Angulars router you need to have server-side support for HTML5 pushState that actually does that redirecting. Why do you do it yourself in Angular code? Could be that I misinterpret something.

Comment: Friend, can you fetch me with a code whatever you are standing with, which will resolve the current problem I'm facing?

Comment: Actually I don't know what your issue is. I'm just wondering why you do the rewriting on the client. This is the common issue devs run into when the server isn't configured for HTML5 pushState http://stackoverflow.com/a/36310728/217408

Comment: But I don't want to go for 'HashLocationStrategy' because some vendor like twitter bootstrap and other, uses Hash location for there own purpose but with absolute path I don't face those kind of problems

Comment: I have seen others mentioned using your strategy but I have no knowlege of any implications. Maybe someone else can provide more help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111455/discussion-between-akhilesh-kumar-and-gunter-zochbauer).