# @angular/router not rendering the routes properly with parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm using:
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1" 
"@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1"
I'm trying to have multiple parameters for my Home Page, my routes are

```
@Routes([
    {path: '/', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: '/:mode', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: '/:mode/:email', component: HomeComponent}
]);
```

When I access http://localhost:2368/test it works and I get 
RouteParams.params.mode == 'test'
However, when I try to add the second parameter by accessing http://localhost:2368/test/email I get:
GET http://localhost:2368/test/js/app.js 404 (Not Found)
The browser is trying to load the app.js from test/js url which obviously doesn't exist as test is suppose to be my first parameter.

Another problem I'm having, when I try to add a real email address as the parameter I get:
Cannot GET /test@email.com

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
The 404 error as due to my webpack config which was using the relative path.
but I still can't run the url with the two router parameters

Comment: So is the 404 now gone after fixing paths? What error do you get now? I guess your issue is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser

Comment: well basically I need to have multiple parameters for one route
{path: '/page/:param1/:param2/:param3', component: HomeComponent} but when I navigate to page/value1/value2/value3 I get: Cannot match any routes. Current segment: 'value3'. Available routes: ['/page/:param1/:param2/:param3']

Comment: That sounds like a new-router error. Can you try to invert the order of the routes in `@RouteConfig()` (`/` last, `/:mode/:email` first)`?

Comment: The order doesn't seem to make any difference, I've also tried with only one route

Comment: How do you navigate to `page/value1/value2/value3`?

Comment: I'm typing the url in the browser

Comment: What happens when you use a `routerLink` in the root component to navigate to this path?

Comment: I've added 
ngOnInit() {
        this.router.navigate(['/value1/value2']);
} on my appComponent and that worked correctly, but it kinda misses the point no?

Comment: I guess I would need to see a Plunker where this can reproduced.

Comment: can I share the code with you via github?

Comment: I don't want to run it locally. I would look at a Plunker. A GitHub repo usually contains way more code than is necessary to reproduce and I don't wan't to investigate a whole project.

Comment: ok i'll prepare a plunker.

Comment: here: http://plnkr.co/edit/2PzeOfsdFrZacUN8XOW9

Comment: Let me know if you need anything else, thanks

Comment: I added `<base href=".">` in `<head>` and commented out `APP_BASE_HREF` and the error got away. `"."` is the right value for Plunker and a different value might be required with your local setup http://plnkr.co/edit/diDmX3r46lcg8bTz06IL?p=preview

Comment: yes on my local I've just added:
provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: "/" }),
    provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }) on my boostrap and everything works now!!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I've added the two lines marked with the arrows and it works now.

```
bootstrap(App, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: "/" }), <-------- Added
    provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }) <-------- Added
    ]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

thanks for the support Günter Zöchbauer