# Routing to ChildComponent after Refresh using Angular Router RC1

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am a bit lost whether I am approaching my problem correctly or not, or this is simply an issue with the RC1 version of the new router.

I have an ApplicationComponent that serves as the entrypoint.

```
@Routes([
    {path: '/ingredients', component: IngredientComponent},
])
```

The IngredientComponent then defines routes on its own:

```
@Routes([
     {path: '/', component: IngredientListComponent},
     {path: '/:id', component: IngredientDetailComponent}
])
```

To further split the view into a overview and a detail-view. This works well when navigating through the app.

However, when reloading the page Angular seems unable to properly match the URL to the nested child routes. If I refresh the page while being on "/ingredients/1" the following error occurs:

```
Current segment: '2'. Available routes: ['/ingredients']
```

"/ingredients" works fine, whereas "/ingredients/" suffers from the same fate.

Any pointers on how I can fix this? Or is this a wrong approach in general and should I declare all routes in the ApplicationComponent?

Addition:
I know about [this particular issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8481) and have already injected the Router.

Answer (score 2):

This might not fix your problem but currently the order of routes is significant <strike>(should be fixed soon)</strike> (here to stay)

The less specific routes should come last:

```
@Routes([
     {path: '/:id', component: IngredientDetailComponent}
     {path: '/', component: IngredientListComponent},
])
```

See also [Angular 2.0 router not working on reloading the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser)