# href="#" redirects to 404 page in angularjs 2

Tags: angular

I have a html theme which uses href="#" for opening sidebar menu and also uses the hash href='#' for tab switching - but in angularjs 2 I am unable to use it, the moment I click on it to open side-Menu or for Tab Switch - The browser page is changed and generally goes to 404 Error else refreshes the page itself

Currently I am studying the [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/HashLocationStrategy-class.html) in the API docs, but no luck yet. Do let me know how you solved this issue

update: hashLocationStrategy is not the solution I looking for

---

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6595 you are running into.

Comment: Yes this is the issue ... but what is the solution in angular 2

Comment: I don't think there is one except waiting for a fix to land. There is *again* a new router work-in-progress. Hopefully it will be easier to handle this use case there.

Comment: I am trying to use https://github.com/bbottema/ng2-simple-page-scroll ,but its giving a 404 error - some path issue in referring to the js lib file in node_modules ... any suggestion

Comment: With `HashLocationStrategy`?

Comment: No - i used it with default PathLocationStrategy ... is that the reason I got 404 ?? - how can I switch to HashLocationStrategy - can you give a ref link

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser For `PathLocationStrategy` you need server support.