# Child routes in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

This is my `app.component.ts`:

```js
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', name: 'Home', component: HomePageComponent},
    {path: '/users/...', name: 'Users', component: UsersComponent},
    {path: '/posts', name: 'Posts', component: PostsComponent},
    {path: '/*others', redirectTo: ['Home']}
])

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.template.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/app.style.css'],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, PostsComponent, UsersComponent, HomePageComponent, AddUserComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private router:Router) {
    }

    public isRouteActive(route) {
        return this.router.isRouteActive(this.router.generate(route))
    }
}
```

Here is `users.component.ts`:

```js
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/new', name: 'AddUser', component: AddUserComponent},
    {path: '/', name: 'FakePage', component: FakeComponent, useAsDefault: true},
])
@Component({
    selector: 'users',
    templateUrl: 'app/users.template.html',
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    styles: [`.glyphicon-remove{color: #b20000;} a{text-decoration: none!important;}.btn-add-user{background: #2c3e52;color: white;margin-bottom: 10px}`]
})

export class UsersComponent {
    private _users:User;

    constructor(private _http:Http) {
        var headers = new Headers({"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST"});
        var options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers
        });

        var users = this._http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', options)
            .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data=> {
                this._users = data
            });
    }
}
```

And `users.template.html` is like this:

```html
<h1>Users</h1>

<a class="btn btn-add-user" [routerLink]="['AddUser']">Add User</a>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of _users">
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></a></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, when I visit `Users` page chrome console throws errors:

> Error: Component "AppComponent" has no route named "AddUser".
>       at new BaseException (router-deprecated.umd.js:648)
>       at RouteRegistry.exports.RouteRegistry.RouteRegistry._generate (router-deprecated.umd.js:2389)
>       at RouteRegistry.exports.RouteRegistry.RouteRegistry.generate (router-deprecated.umd.js:2327)
>       at RootRouter.exports.Router.Router.generate (router-deprecated.umd.js:2984)
>       at RouterLink.exports.RouterLink.RouterLink._updateLink (router-deprecated.umd.js:3359)
>       at RouterLink.set [as routeParams] (router-deprecated.umd.js:3371)
>       at DebugAppView._View_UsersComponent0.detectChangesInternal (UsersComponent.template.js:146)
>       at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (core.umd.js:9996)
>       at DebugAppView.detectChanges (core.umd.js:10084)
>       at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (core.umd.js:10016)

And `Add User` button doesn't work.

Comment: You have two routes with the same name, this could be a problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't provide `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` on every component. They must only be provided once, either in the root component or in `bootstrap()`

Remove

```
ROUTER_PROVIDERS
```

from `providers: []` of your `UserComponent` and add it to `AppComponent`

**Hint**

- CORS headers

  ```
  var headers = new Headers({"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST"});
  ```

have to be added by the server to allow CORS requests. Adding them on the client has no effect.

See also [Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

- providers

There is no need to add components to `directives: [...]` that are added by the router. Only directives directly used in the template need to be listed (except when they are already provided by `PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES` like `ngFor`)

Comment: No errors after this corrections but Add User button doesn't renders desired page!

Comment: Do you use ´PathLocationStrategy` (default) or `HashLocationStrategy`? Is your server configured to support it? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser

Comment: I forgot to add router-outlet , fixed now, thank you.