# Angular 2 Router strange null call

Tags: wordpress, angular, routes

**Problem**

Im loading some menu items from the Wordpress Rest API, then navigate to the page/:id with the correct id of the wordpress page. Everything works fine except of that:

Early when my page is loading I get this null call in the network section of the chrome developer. This is locally, on my server its also a 404 NOT FOUND.

[image: www.mydomain.com/null]

**Setup**

- Angular 2 + Typescript (Angular 2 RC2, Router 3.0.0-alpha.6)
- Wordpress REST API

**Code**

Template

```
<header></header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

Routing

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '/page/:id', component: PageComponent },
  { path: '/page/home', component: PageComponent, index: true }
];
```

Header.ts

```
this.myService.getNavigation()
    .subscribe(
        menuItems => {
            this.menuItems = menuItems;

            this.router.navigate(['/page', this.menuItems[0].title]);
        },
        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

Main.ts

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ...APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    ...HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ...ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    ...ENV_PROVIDERS,
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
  ])
```

**Assumption**

I guess it has something to do with my routing setup. When I comment out the `<router-outlet>` it does not happen, everything else works good.

**Question**

What is this strange call at /null and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser

Comment: Seems like most of the people fixed it by using HashLocationStrategy what I already do.

Comment: This means you get the error even with `HashLocationStrategy` enabled? Can you show the code how you enable it?

Comment: All my urls already get the # and I can refresh it without any problems :) Only this /null network route is disturbing me. Added the bootstrap code.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have somewhere `<img [attr.src]="var">` or similar.

Comment: I only have two image tags in my whole project and the error still exists if I remove them. I can really remove a lot of code and the error still comes. Im pretty sure its a routing problem.

Comment: You could add XHR break point in chrome to trace caller: http://devtoolsecrets.com/secret/debugging-xhr-breakpoints.html