# Why doesn't this route match when navigating to it directly?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

For the record: This is using the currently rather new `"@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.8"`, the route definitions are at the bottom of the post.

When attempting to navigate in my application the behaviour is different depending on whether I enter the URL directly or following a link:

- **Works:** Entering `http://localhost:9292` in the address-bar, correctly forwards to `http://localhost:9292/about`
- **Works:** Navigating directly to `http://localhost:9292/about` via the address-bar
- **Works:** If I navigate to `http://localhost:9292/about/projects` via an `<a>` tag, in the context of the `FrontComponent` and the `[routerLink]="['projects']"` attribute, the routing works just fine.
- **Broken:** Directly navigating to `http://localhost:9292/about/projects` results in the following error message (shortened Stacktrace):

  ```
  Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes: 'projects' ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot match any routes: 'projects'
  Stack trace:
  applyRedirects/<@http://localhost:9292/node_modules/@angular/router/apply_redirects.js:29:34
  Observable.prototype.subscribe@http://localhost:9292/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:52:57
  ```

What could I possibly be doing wrong here? Is there possibly any way to see all routes that have been rejected in the error message?

**Edit** because this has been suggested numerous times now: I don't suspect this is a server-side issue. The previous routing via `router-deprecated` worked fine and the `HTML` served from the failing route looks just fine. But just in case, this is the relevant server side routing code (`ruby` with `sinatra`):

```ruby
# By now I have too often mistakenly attempted to load other assets than
# HTML files from "user facing" URLs, mostly due to paths that should have
# been absolute but weren't. This route attempts to catch all these
# mistakes rather early, so that the show up as a nice 404 error in the
# browsers debugging tools
get /^\/(about|editor)\/.*\.(css|js)/ do
  halt 404, "There are no assets in `editor` or `about` routes"
end

# Matching the meaningful routes the client knows. This enables navigation
# even if the user submits a "deep link" to somewhere inside the
# application.
index_path = File.expand_path('index.html', settings.public_folder)
get '/', '/about/?*', '/editor/*' do
  send_file index_path
end

# Catchall for everything that goes wrong
get '/*' do
  halt 404, "Not found"
end
```

I do not suspect that this is due to wrong route definitions (the routing does work via the link), but for the sake of completeness these are the routes:

*front/front.routes.ts*:

```ts
export const FrontRoutes : RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/about',
        terminal: true
    },
    {
        path : 'about',
        component: FrontComponent,
        children : [
            { path: 'projects', component: ProjectListComponent},
            { path: '',         component: AboutComponent},
        ]
    }
]
```

*editor/editor.routes.ts*:

```ts
export const EditorRoutes : RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: "editor/:projectId",
        component : EditorComponent,
        children : [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'settings', terminal: true},
            { path: 'settings', component : SettingsComponent },
            { path: 'schema', component : SchemaComponent },
            { path: 'query/create', component : QueryCreateComponent },
            { path: 'query/:queryId', component : QueryEditorComponent },
            { path: 'page/:pageId', component : PageEditorComponent },
        ]
    }
]
```

*app.routes.ts*:

```ts
import {EditorRoutes}                   from './editor/editor.routes'
import {FrontRoutes}                    from './front/front.routes'

export const routes : RouterConfig = [
    ...FrontRoutes,
    ...EditorRoutes,
]

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)
]
```

Comment: Make sure your server side code returns correct HTML page when accessing `http://localhost:9292/about/projects`

Comment: When typing full URL in address bar, the request go first to the server and angular is executed later on client side,

Comment: If that was the problem, navigating to `http://localhost:9292/about` shouldn't work either, but it does. I have taken care of this on the server.

Comment: True, but I would say to double check, because it looks like a server side problem

Comment: I triple checked, this is 100% not the problem.

Comment: Your server doesn't support HTML5 pushState

Comment: What does the server have to do with the HTML5 history API?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser

Comment: Sorry, but I really can't see how this is related: From my understanding the question clearly shows that I took care of serving the `index.html` for all relevant routes and in fact I do see it sent over the wire. What I am getting is **not** a server-side `404` error but a angular exception.

Comment: What happens if you remove `{ path: '',         component: AboutComponent},` additionally try to set `terminal: true` for `ProjectListComponent`.

Comment: Exactly the same behaviour. (Apart that I cant navigate to `/about` either any more of course.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `"/"` as value to the `base` tag of the `index.html` to make the router resolve child paths correctly. This is [not in line with the offical docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#base-href) but seems to work.

Comment: Lost two hours because documentation sad '.'