# SVG sprites angular 2

Tags: svg, angular

Right inside of body tag I have svg sprites

```
<svg version="1.1" width="0" height="0" style="position: absolute;">
   <symbol id="icon-mail" viewBox="0 0 15 13">
     ...
   </symbol>
</svg>
```

And I use it inside angular 2 app like this

```
<svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#icon-mail" /></svg>
```

If I load main page for example `localhost:9000` sprites are rendered, but if I fully load other url `localhost:9000/users` sprites are not rendered.

What is the best way using sprites in angular 2 app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `APP_BASE_HREF` instead of `<base>` element.

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}])
```

See also [Angular 2.0 router not working on reloading the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser/36310728#36310728)

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more, please... how to do this in router v3?

Comment: Thanks a lot Günter, works perfectly fine! However it's still a bit fuzzy, what is the connection of routing and svg...

Comment: Glas to hear. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: There is a better explanation of why this technique works here https://stacksandfoundations.com/2016/06/22/svgs-funciri-angular2-and-the-base-tag/

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone finds this answer after the 2.0 release, the new way to do this is: add import at the top of the file with other imports

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from "@angular/common";
```

add `APP_BASE_HREF` in with providers array in `@NgModule`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    // your code here
  ],
  imports: [
   // your code here
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useValue: "/"
    },
    // your code here
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

delete `<base href="/">` from `index.html`