# Angular 2 rc4 can not go to page by typing the url to the address bar

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-routing

I 've just update my project to version rc 4 and got the problem.

When I use the systemjs to config my project, everything is ok.

When I run the project with webpack (I am using the [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) ) the project was run successfully, no bugs. I can go to every link which was config by [routerLink].

But with the same link if I type the url to the browser's address bar. There was nothing happened. My app did not load anything.
Here is some screen shot from my project:

[Screen shot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByiF2Cvlx688WDdqZmRuekVPV1k)

Can anyone help me? I am thank you so much.

Comment: Your link isn't public, please host your screenshot at some public site like imgur, or adjust your google settings. Anyway, it seems like you are missing `<base href="/">` in your index.html

Comment: Sorry,the link  is public now. I 've already put the <base href="/"> in the <head></head> of the index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This needs to be handled by your back-end server.

You need to send all requests to the index page so that Angular can pick up the request and resolve the route from there.

What's happening is when you visit your index(/) page Angular takes over and when you click on a [routerlink] it pretends to change the page in the browser (it's not actually doing anything with the server).  When you visit any page that isn't the index by typing in the URL then you are not loading your Angular app and therefore it's not able to edit routes in the browser.  By forwarding all routes to the index we're letting Angular decide how all routes should be handled, instead of the server.

Comment: Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser

Comment: Thank you so much, I resolved my problem. The static path to my index.html was set to folder dev instead of dist. So when I load my project in production mode, It can't find the right index.html

Comment: Excellent!  I am glad you fixed your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Ìf you serve the content by JS. Add this code to express route

```
var path = require('path')

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/static/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.