# Include javascript file for each Component Angular2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

When I add a javascript file in my index.html and I use some function it work just for the first time but when I refresh my page it not wokring so I need some way to include for each component a file javascript to avoid this problem

Answer (score 1):

I **think** you're talking about routing.  For Angular2 routes to work you need to make sure that the back-end server redirects all requests to your index page otherwise Angular will not be loaded, and will not be able to show the correct content/component for the current route

More on this here: [Angular 2 rc4 can not go to page by typing the url to the address bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38453795/angular-2-rc4-can-not-go-to-page-by-typing-the-url-to-the-address-bar/38454577#38454577)