# Angular2 refreshing page in 'second level route?' throws errors

Tags: typescript, angular, routes

I built the project using angular-cli.
My routes look like this:

```
  export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },   
    { path: 'users/new', component: NewUsersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]  },   
    { path: 'users/edit', component: EditUsersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]  },         
  ];

  export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes),
    AuthGuard
  ];
```

If i refresh the page in `http://localhost:4200/users` there are no problems.

**If i hit refresh page** in `http://localhost:4200/users/new` or in `http://localhost:4200/users/edit` , i get a world of Erros:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/users/assets/css/styles.css 
new:31 GET http://localhost:4200/users/vendor/es6-shim/es6-shim.js 
new:31 GET http://localhost:4200/users/vendor/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js 
new:31 GET http://localhost:4200/users/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js 
.... etc....
```

Otherwise the app works fine.
**Why is this happening and how can i fix it?**

Comment: did you add  <base href="/"> ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser

Comment: Now i remember i changed the base href from "/" to "." so it can work on a WAMP server. Now i changed it back and it looks ok. Thanks. I will figure it out later how to make it work again in WAMP.