# Angular and IIS WebApplication (or virtual directory)

Tags: angular, iis, web-applications, angular2-template

We have webserver with an IIS website and an IIS Web Application underneath. The web application's root is: **http://website/webapplication/**.
When deployed I get the following error in the browser:

> http://website/app/app.component.html 404 (Not Found)
>
> app/app.component.html 404 (Not Found)

My component:

```
@Component({
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "./app/app.component.html"
})
```

The file app.component.html does indeed not exist under **/app/app.component.html**, but it does exist at: **/webapplication/app/app.component.html**.

So, my conclusion is that Angular only works when in the root of a website.
In the html header I have set the  tag to: `<base href="/webapplication/">`, but that doesn't help.

It seems like a normal setup, I can't believe the template resolving in Angular fails, I must be missing something... Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: did you figure out the solution ? I am having the same issue thanks

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't use most of the suggestions on the web regarding fixing this issue, I have no idea why.  I played around with settings util I got it working.  Here is what I used:

- IIS 10.0
- Angular 6.1.0 project
- Virtual Directory converted to application
- App Pool: No Managed Code

webconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
       <action type="Rewrite" url="/myapp/index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

my root index.html file:

```
<base href="./">   <---- make sure you have the dot in there!
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use Url Rewrite and get this working, the only long-term solution to this problem is to use HashLocationStrategy.

[Angular 2.0 router not working on reloading the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser/33573548#33573548)