# Auth0 Allowed Web Origins for app hosted in Azure

Tags: auth0, azure-webapps

I have a SPA application that I've developed using Auth0 for my IDP.  When developing locally, I set the Auth0 Allowed Web Origins settings to `http://localhost:8080` and got everything working.

Now I've deployed my app to Azure as a Web App -- so my app is addressed like so: `myapp.azurewebsites.net`.  I've also included a custom domain so that I can access my app like this: `myapp.mydomain.com`.

I went into my Auth0 dashboard and updated the Allowed Web Origins to include `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net` and `https://myapp.mydomain.com`

However, I can no longer get Auth0 to authenticate.  When I make the call to the auth endpoint at Auth0, I get a callback to my `signin-oidc` endpoint with the error

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

My guess is that I'm not getting the Allowed Web Origins correct.  What can I do to get this working again?

Answer (score -1):

You are looking in a wrong direction (just like me :) ). Solution is adding web.config to your project. Discussed lot's of time here before.

[Angular2 - page refresh 404ing when hosted in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38823595/angular2-page-refresh-404ing-when-hosted-in-azure)

[Error : The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019874/error-the-resource-you-are-looking-for-has-been-removed-had-its-name-changed)