# Angular2 deploy in docker container disturbs routing

Tags: angular, docker

i want to deploy my Angular2/ts app within a docker container. I found the following tutorial which works really good:
[Link](https://www.eyesoreinc.com/getting-started-angular2-using-docker-compose/). So my docker-compose.yml now is:

```
version: '2'

services:
  httpd:
    image: httpd:latest
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
      - ./node_modules:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/node_modules
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  npm:
    image: treyjones/npm:latest
    volumes:
      - ./:/npm
  tsc:
    image: treyjones/tsc:latest
    volumes:
      - ./:/tsc
```

but I have the problem that the routing does not work right.

I can reach my app via

> http://localhost:80/

and it redirects me to

> http://localhost:80/data

So to this point everything works great. But i I refresh my page, or try to reach it via

> http://localhost:80/data

I get an error:

> "GET /data HTTP/1.1" 404 205

I've already had this problem before I used a docker container, and solved it using live-server, as mentioned in
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser). Which means that I added the script:

> "serve": "concurrently \"live-server --port=5556 --entry-file=index.html \" \"gulp\" \"npm run tsc:w\" "

within my package.json.

But I do not know how I can integrate live-server into my docker-configuration or how I can manipulate httpd such that I can an option like the option

> --entry-file=index.html

of the live-server.

Answer (score 0):

1. You either have to configure `httpd` as described here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html. That means creating your own docker image based on `httpd:latest` that adds the remapping of the routes.
2. Stop using httpd and use `lite-server` to serve the files you want, the way you want. Again, creating your own docker image that does that.

Comment: ok, i hoped that there is already a docker image which provides the functionality for lite-server