# Bookmarkable routes in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to develop app. with the help of **routes**(**Lazy Loading**) in angular 2(**RC5**). I found that I'm not able to bookmark any route, even I tried to directly put link in URL but it didn't work, I googled the problem, but not able to figure it out!!

Here are some snippet of my core:

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

     <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css">
    <base href = ''>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <main-app class='container'>Loading...</main-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

**AppComponent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'main-app',
    template: `
        <h4>Today: {{ todaysDate | date:"dd/MM/yy"}}</h4>
        <nav>
            <a routerLink = '/home' routerLinkActive = 'active'>Home Tab</a>
            <a routerLink = '/clients' routerLinkActive = 'active'>Clients Tab</a>
            <a routerLink = '/aboutus' routerLinkActive = 'active'>About Us Tab</a>
        </nav>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
export class AppComponent{
    ....
    ....
}
```

**AppRouter:**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { homeComponent } from '../home.component/home.component';
import { clientsComponent } from '../clients.component/clients.component';
import { aboutusComponent } from '../aboutus.component/aboutus.component';

const routes = [
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: homeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'clients',
        component: clientsComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'aboutus',
        component: aboutusComponent
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        component: homeComponent
    }
];
export const appRouteProviders = [];
export const appRoutes = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

When I tried to put a link **directly** in URL, say - http://localhost:3000/clients or http://localhost:3000/aboutus , it doesn't work!! Then Why these links are not bookmarkable ? What **Lazy Loading** exactly do then? Please help me out.

Comment: Sounds like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser

Answer (score 3):

Do you have this line define on your index.html

```
<base href='/' >
```

Comment: Yes, normally its work fine, but I'm not able to jump to any particular URL directly.!!

Comment: Can you update your question and add your index.html code please. <base href='/' > should of solve your issue.

Comment: <base href=''> != <base href="/" > add the forward slash and try again. Also move that to first line of your <head>.