# Rxjs is not found in production

Tags: javascript, angular, playframework, sbt, rxjs

I have an angular2 and play app from [here](https://github.com/joost-de-vries/play-angular2-typescript). Everything works fine when I run it in dev mode with **sbt run**. However I would like to test the production, so I do **sbt dist**, load the app and get the following errors in console.

> http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/rxjs/rx.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   zone.min.js:1 Error: (SystemJS) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/rxjs/rx.js(…)e.invoke @ zone.min.js:1

However when I click on the link I see that a file has been loaded.

Here is the [code](https://github.com/joost-de-vries/play-angular2-typescript/blob/master/app/views/index1.scala.html) for system js configuration I am using. Does anyone hava an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer then how is it possible that in dev mode everything works?

Comment: I had the suspicion that you use another server in production.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer no, I am using the same machine

Comment: and the same HTTP server?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer what do you mean? It is running on the same port on localhost. I can see some files from rxjs has been loaded correctly i.e. rxjs/Subject.js or rxjs/Observable.js

Comment: I just mean that this error usually occurs when the HTTP server used doesn't support HTML5 pushState, this is why I posted the link above.

Comment: yes I support pushState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was deprecated imports.

change

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/rx"
```

to

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable"
```

in ts source files.