# Angular2 router with param reload page change get CSS file directory

Tags: css, angular, reload, router, parameters

Normally if I click link on home link to detail link, like `<a routerLink="/detail/{{record.TA001}}">`,it work well and css file got very well.

As only I refresh this detail page, like `localhost:3000/detail/0006`
it got data ok, but get CSS file change the directory to the detail instead root directory, could not get the CSS file. My detail component is in `app/content` directory.

[image]

My `index.html` and CSS file in project root directory.
router :

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'contact',
    component: Contactcomponent
  },
  {
    path: 'detail/:id',
    component: Detailcomponent
  },
  { path: '',
   component: Contentcomponent
  }
```

*My project directory is like this:*

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser/36310728#36310728

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have known how to resolve this problem ,just router directive /detail/0005 change /0005, it woke fine .  i think it was if  router for root so you just can use one level just fine .it could not use two level approch , if u router not for root ,it can use it .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use relative path instead of calculating every time the absolute one (with ../ ../../ etc.) you should use moduleID property in your component declaration as explained [here.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check If u include base href="/"  in index.html before including css/stylesheet