# Angular 2 - can redirect route, but using direct link doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-routing

So this is what my app-routing.module.ts looks like

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { IndexComponent } from './index.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error.component';

const routes = [ 
    { path: 'hira', redirectTo: 'search', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'search', component: AppComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'main', component: AppComponent },
    { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'error'}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

When I go into the site e.g. `www.website.com/hira` it will redirect to `www.website.com/hira/search`. However if I then use that link directly (refresh it), it will not work and give me a 404.

So I'm wondering if I need to make children or something.

Also, right now I have `<base href="./">` within the hira folder. And the reason why I have `path: 'hira'` is because it doesn't work without it, so I was also wondering if there was a way to make it relative to the subfolder hira.

**Resolved:**
Used hashhistory instead. Could use browserhistory but requires htaccess

Comment: you work with ng cli? or how do you run your project?

Comment: I just use the npm start, and I'm just accessing it like a typical apache server (not using their ip:port because it seems to not work well with php files).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser. I believe you are trying to request a page that does not really exist

Answer (score 2):

### **Workaround**:

Use hashbangs. However, I would not recommend them.

`@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes), {useHash: true} ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})`

### **Fix**:

Depending on the web server, configure it to redirect all the requests including 404, 401 to the same index.html page.

Angular handles all the requests from there on and is able to redirect to different paths.

Here is a [response](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8788#issuecomment-221766924) from the core Angular team member to a similar issue.