# Rails app on NGINX server, I want to change the routes for rails_admin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rails-admin

I have a Rails server where nginx routes `/` to `/api`, and I have rails_admin gem installed. I can access the admin panel at `/api/admin`, but all the models listed on the admin page link to `/admin/:model`. I can't seem to find a way to get the links to route to `/api/admin/:model` instead.

I have set the following in `application.rb`:

```
config.relative_url_root = "/api"
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/api"
ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']  = "/api"
ENV['ROOT_URL']  = "/api"
```

But the admin page links have not changed.

If I change `routes.rb` to have rails_admin under a namespace, the problem is not fixed: the admin page now becomes `api/api/admin` and the links go to `api/admin/:model`, but with the routes it requires `api/api/admin/:model` instead.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This answer may help you if you actually want to add `/api` for whole rails app, not only rails_admin.

You do not need those configs in your `application.rb` for it. Read this doc: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/nginx/deploy/ruby/

Here's example of my configs:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name www.mydomain.com;
  root /var/www/AppName/current/client/dist;
  error_page 404 =200 /index.html;
  location ~ ^/api(/.*|$) {
    alias /var/www/AppName/current/public$1;  # <-- be sure to point to 'public'!
    passenger_base_uri /api;
    passenger_app_root /var/www/AppName/current;
    passenger_document_root /var/www/AppName/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_app_env production;
  }
}
```

P.S. here's the explanation for `error_page 404 =200 /index.html;` -
[Angular 2.0 router not working on reloading the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser)