# angular 2 404 on refresh

Tags: angular, webpack

I am getting a 404 on page refresh in my angular 2 app. I have useHash set to false. I am using web-pack and it works fine in development but in production it doesn't work. I this is because in development i have

```
devServer : {
  port : METADATA.port,
  host : METADATA.host,
  historyApiFallback : true,
  watchOptions : {
    aggregateTimeout : 300,
    poll : 1000
  }
},
```

How can i make this work using `http-server` in production, without setting useHash to true?

Comment: Return `index.html` on the server for every invalid request (instead of 404)

Comment: how do i do that with http-server there doesn't seem to be any options do i need to set something in my webpack.config if so what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2.0 router not working on reloading the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved this i used `spa-http-server` which has a `--push-state` flag that makes all URIs respond with index.html.