# Single Page App (ng2) and .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, angular, single-page-application

Should be a pretty simple question but I have an NG2 app that will run an apache server, when navigating to the app url i.e. localhost:4200 it will check if the user is authenticated and if they arent authenticated it will redirect to the /login url. This works well but if a user refreshes the webpage on the /login url the app wont load (the base href is "/").

Should I setup a 301 redirect in my .htaccess to redirect hits to /login to /?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2.0 router not working on reloading the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser)