# Error : The requested URL was not found on this server(page not loading after build when we refresh the page)

Tags: php, angular

In developer section (localhost:4200) is working fine. After completing the build application loading and working fine but url when i type and press enter it is not working.

my router:

```
export const appRoutes : Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'material', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {path:'material',component: MaterialComponent},
];
```

and my module.ts file

```
imports: [            
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,{ enableTracing: true }),BrowserModule,FormsModule,HttpModule,MaterialModule,BrowserAnimationsModule,RouterModule    
  ],
```

Error:

[image]

Why giving custom url is not working after build?

Comment: url wokring fine. but when we refresh the page showing Error:404

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Angular takes care of the url after the dns (`localhost:4200`) part. So when you type `localhost:4200/someurl`, The network will query your backend for that full url, and if it doesn't exists you will get a 404. You have 2 options here:

1) Use HashLocation Strategy which I don't recommend because it breaks AoT.

2) Define a redirection function in your back-end code. For nodejs we do it like this:

```
app.get('/*',  function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname + '/dist' });
});
```

Related topic: [Angular 2.0 router not working on reloading the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser)

Comment: @echonax-just now I have included hashlocation it's working fine form me. But i don't now how to apply redirection using angular 2, can you help me to resolve this one. Back end i am using php

Comment: @SivaUnique It's not related with angular as we've discussed :-) unfortunately I don't know php :(

Comment: Yes Echonax, can you tell me the logic how we will do this one(i will build logic in php)

Comment: @SivaUnique I've added php tag to your question, hopefully someone who knows php would answer it.

Answer (score 0):

> I have solved using Hash. We need to import below modules in module.ts

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

> and we need to include providers as given below in module.ts file.

```
  providers: [AppCommonService,{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
```

Comment: If you use hashlocation strategy, you won't be able to use ahead of time compilation.