# Routed apps must fallback to index.html with Angular and Rails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, heroku, routes

I am working on a rails api (no views) app with angular 5 as front-end. Both frameworks are integrated in the same project following the structure proposed namely [here](https://blogstephenarifin.wordpress.com/2017/01/09/angular-2-and-ruby-on-rails-on-heroku/).

The application is deployed on Heroku. The first page of the app is e.g. `example.com/home`. When I refresh the page in the browser, the page did not display anymore and I get a 404 error in the browser. Same for links from emails.

There is indeed no rails route for `/home` as this is a angular route.

I found this [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser) that is refeering to this [angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml) stating that a fallback routing to `index.html` has to be setup on the web server to handle linking from emails, external sources or refreshing pages.

I did the test on a local install with nginx. By default the refresh yields a 404 error but adding the rule in the config file:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

solve the issue.

How can I achieve this on Heroku?

Comment: I may have found a solution thanks to Heroku support using [this article](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-cli-deployment-host-your-angular-2-app-on-heroku-3f266f13f352)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by splitting the deployment of my application in two heroku applications: one for the back-end and one for the front-end.

The back-end application running the rails server with the api.

The front-end application running the node server.js as described [here](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-cli-deployment-host-your-angular-2-app-on-heroku-3f266f13f352).

This solves the page reload issue as the node server is handling the request for the front-end path.

The parameterization of the api url is done for the front-end using environment variables as show [here](https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/angular-2-and-environment-variables-59c57ba643be).