# got this error, Error: Cannot match any routes

Tags: angular2-routing

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LmfinComponent } from '../app/lmfin/lmfin.component';
import { MfinComponent } from './mfin/mfin.component';
import { GenFunctionProvider } from './gen-function.module';
import {DetailpembayaranComponent } from './detailpembayaran/detailpembayaran.component';

const appRoutes:Routes = [                 //removed export
  {                                        //removed square bracket
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/mfin',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },{
     path: 'list',
     component: LmfinComponent
  },{
    path: 'mfin/:id',
    component: MfinComponent
  },{
    path: 'detailpembayaran',
    component: DetailpembayaranComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash:true})
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

i'm still new at routing, when i try to makes routing, i got this error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.

anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You default path to redirect `/mfin`

You no path with `/mfin` you have URL `/mfin/:id`. This is not match with `/mfin`

So need to add route URL of `/mfin`.

Comment: so, how can i redirectto mfin/:id? I try to place mfin/:id on "RedirectTo" but it got me another error..

Comment: you need to pass id like  mfin/:id == mfin/10

Comment: if you do not have ID then change Route path from mfin/:id to /mfin

Answer (score 0):

Try this, As far as I understood you are missing some codes in index.html. Check whether you have below code in your index.html head section. If not add it and see.

```
<base href="/">
```

Also ensure your server has configured for HTML5 pushState like explained in [Angular 2.0 router not working on reloading the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser)

I hope this will resolve your problem. If you have any doubts or suggestion let me know.