# Using nginx as reverse proxy for apache and want more htaccess control

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx in a reverse proxy configuration with apache2. I have used other, preconfigured web servers in this way and enjoyed complete control over redirects from an .htaccess file.

My current configuration does not allow for this. First, I'll explain what happens.

Let's say I want to redirect /google to http://google.com. I add the following line to my .htaccess file.

```
redirect 307 /google http://google.com
```

I know it's working because I can test with curl from my server. This is hitting apache directly, behind the proxy.

```
curl -I localhost:8080/google
```

and I get a 307 as I would expect.

But if this request hits nginx from the outside, nginx knows there is no such file in the web root and responds 404.

Is there a configuration change I can make to remedy this?

Here's my nginx configuration file for this vhost.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /var/www/mywebsite.com/html;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  server_name mywebsite.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/mywebsite.com.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/mywebsite.com.error.log;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }
  location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  }
  location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

It seems that I might need to take the reverse approach and proxy everything but exclude certain file types from the proxy.

Thanks for advice folks!

Comment: Do want to serve that redirect to google with nginx or you want to forward it to apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to forward that request to `/google` to **apache**, then just change the `location ~ \.php$` pattern to include the request you desire:

```
location ~ (/google/?)|(\.php)$ {
```

On the other hand if you want **nginx** to handle the redirect you can add new rule:

```
location ~ /google {
    return 307 http://google.com;
}
```

Just make sure to put it **before** the `location` block which contains `try_files`.

EDIT:
To forward all requests that don't hit a file use this:

```
location /
{
    if (!-f $request_filename) #test if a static file does not exists
    { 
        # forward the request if there is no file to serve:
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

Additionally if you want for nginx to also serve entire directories then add another condition:

```
!-d $request_filename
```

Also note that if you want only specific files to be served then instead `location /` use the pattern to match those files. For example if you want to serve only `jpg`'s and `css`'s use

```
location ~ \.(jpg|css)$
```

EDIT2: Here you have a simplified version of your script, which is also more robust - lets you serve only the types of files you want:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.lcl;
    root /home/www/test;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @apache;
    }

    location @apache
    {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work for this case, but I want something that works for all possible cases. Is it not possible to tell nginx, if it's one of a certain group of static files then serve it, but if it's anything else go ahead and proxy it to apache? That seems like it will give me what I need.

Comment: Ofcourse it is possible. Your question just wasn't clear about that. I'll update the answer in a minute.

Comment: I was gradually working my way to that part of the question. ;) Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps I implemented your example incorrectly, but that didn't work for this. [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19482006/2535178), however, does what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes, I was just about to shorten it in simillar way. Well, I'll post it anyway.